# Power BI sort by column (Date) is producing different results on two graphs

Tags: sorting, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two graphs that are based off of the same dataset. I had an issue with sorting the graph chronologically, so I sorted by a YearMonNum column. The data looks something like this:

| id | YearMonNum | MonthYearShort | Views | Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202105 | May '21 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 202106 | Jun '21 | 58 | 42 |
| 3 | 202107 | Jul'21 | 264 | 161 |

And my graphs look something like this in Power BI:

[image: Image of two graphs]

And the problem is that the sort by option on both graphs are different, which I don't understand. If I click the ellipses on the first graph

[image: Image2]

I can sort ascending or descending, whereas the second one doesn't allow sorting ascending or descending. Also, for the first graph, I have to sort by YearMonNum in order for it to look like the second graph

[image: Image3].

How do I get both graphs to look like the second one?

Answer (score 0):

The sort options in the graphs differ because you have chosen a column (MonthYearShort) to sort on in the first graph whereas you haven't chosen a sort column in the second graph. You can identify which sort column is chosen as it appears in **bold**. Choosing a sort column allows you to set the direction of the sort & it defaults to the first option (descending). To align your graphs, choose the same sort column & direction for both.